# Working with NSArray in Obj C

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, enumeration

I am currently trying to make a simple craps app for the iPhone.

In the model I have a method:

```
-(NSString *)resultsOfRoll:(int)firstRoll :(int)secondRoll
{
    NSString *results = @"";
    NSArray *naturalNumbers = @[@7,@11];
    NSArray *losingNumbers = @[@2, @3, @12];
    NSArray *pointNumbers = @[@4,@5,@6,@8,@9,@10,@11];
    int sum = firstRoll + secondRoll;
    if(sum in naturalNumbers)
    {
       return @"You rolled a natural! You won";
    }

    return results
}
```

But I am getting an error. I am pretty new to Obj C and I haven't used much enumeration(If that is wrong please correct me) yet. Could someone let me know if I am initializing the loop correctly and how I can check to see if the sum (roll + roll) is in an array?
Also, does my method name look correct? I am coming from Java and these method sigs are still a little confusing for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if(sum in naturalNumbers)` obviously isn't valid syntax. You're using something like 'for in' and with an int instead of an object.

What you want is:

```
if ([naturalNumbers containsObject:@(sum)]) {
```

Which asks the array if it contains an `NSNumber` instance containing the `sum`.

Your method doesn't name the second parameter, which is legal but not encouraged. It would be better as:

```
-(NSString *)resultsOfRoll:(int)firstRoll secondRoll:(int)secondRoll
```

Comment: Thanks I got that to work @Wain, didn't mean to select that other answer. Following MVC convention if i wanted to create a method that stored the value of the last roll (when a person rolls a point value) so they can continue rolling would I put this info in the model or should I put it into the Controller?

Comment: Sounds like an immediate result that doesn't need to be stored so the controller.